# Which View should I use for this? Android Studio

Tags: android, view, dialog, popupwindow, custom-view

I have such a question, I am developing an Android Application for learning languages.  In my application, you can read books and when you click on a word, a window should appear on top of the word.  This window will translate the word into the desired language and the ability to save the word.  The question is what should I use to implement this window?

(maybe it's a **Dialog** or a **PopupWindow**? But how to make it appear on top of this word?)

*Here is a screenshot from another application to make it clear what I mean.*
[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n6UOb.jpg)

- *I already know how to add a word click listener, get that word and translate it.  The only question is how to implement this View*

Comment: A PopupWindow is appropriate.  Dialog is more for center of the screen, and is generally modal.  The popupwindow.showAtLocation(view, x, y) will show it at position (x,y) relative to the view passed in.  So you just need to call that with the position of the word (plus any padding you want) to display it at the word.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use custom view with tooltip,
this is a great library you can use it : [Android Simple Tooltip](https://github.com/douglasjunior/android-simple-tooltip)

example :

```
View yourView = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.custom_dialog, null);

new SimpleTooltip.Builder(this)
    .anchorView(yourView)
    .text("Texto do Tooltip")
    .gravity(Gravity.END)
    .animated(true)
    .transparentOverlay(false)
    .build()
    .show();
```